# Need help finding an mistake in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I've written a Makefile to build my project and it's doing some things that are unexpected.

I've written a Makefile to take the source files from a directory create target object files in another directory. There are two executable targets App1 and App2.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -MMD -MP

SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = build/obj
BIN_DIR = build/bin

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
SRCS := $(filter-out $(SRC_DIR)/App1.cpp, $(SRCS))
SRCS := $(filter-out $(SRC_DIR)/App2.cpp, $(SRCS))

OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
DEPS = $(OBJS:.o=.d)

$(BIN_DIR)/App1 : $(OBJS) $(OBJ_DIR)/App1.o | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) $(OBJ_DIR)/App1.o -o $(BIN_DIR)/App1

$(BIN_DIR)/App2 : $(OBJS) $(OBJ_DIR)/App2.o | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) $(OBJ_DIR)/App2.o -o $(BIN_DIR)/App2

$(OBJ_DIR)/App1.o : $(SRC_DIR)/App1 | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SRC_DIR)/App1.cpp -o $(OBJ_DIR)/App1.o

$(OBJ_DIR)/App2.o : $(SRC_DIR)/App2.cpp | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SRC_DIR)/App2.cpp -o $(OBJ_DIR)/App2.o

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

-include $(DEPS)
-include $(OBJ_DIR)/App1.d
-include $(OBJ_DIR)/App2.d

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

$(BIN_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)

.PHONY: clean
```

The Makefile is building both executable targets as expected but for App1 something strange is happening. When I build in App1 I see in addition to the executable being generated in the bin directory there another executable, App1, and App1.d being placed in src and I don't understand why.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the description of the problem you're having.  Can you edit your question to make it very simple and clear, perhaps showing the contents of directories, and the output of running `make` (cut and pasted, and formatted properly)?  Are you asking why files `App1.d` are being created?  That's because of the `-MMD -MP` options you've given to the compiler (see your compiler's documentation for what these options do).

Comment: Why do you care where the object files and executables go?  If you're after clean builds then out-of-source building via `VPATH` is even more clean, and probably easier to set up.  On the other hand, why do you *not* care about what source files go into your build?

Comment: You have a typo in your rule for building `$(OBJ_DIR)/App1.o`.  It has `$(SRC_DIR)/App1` as a prerequisite, but you meant `$(SRC_DIR)/App1.cpp`.  That's why `make` builds `$(SRC_DIR)/App1`, or attempts to do so, and when it does, the compiler flags cause `$(SRC_DIR)/App1.d` to be produced as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. Thanks for the help everyone. Here's the corrected Makefile if anyone else wants to know.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -MMD -MP

SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = build/obj
BIN_DIR = build/bin

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
SRCS := $(filter-out $(SRC_DIR)/App1.cpp, $(SRCS))
SRCS := $(filter-out $(SRC_DIR)/App2.cpp, $(SRCS))

OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
DEPS = $(OBJS:.o=.d)

$(BIN_DIR)/App1 : $(OBJS) $(OBJ_DIR)/App1.o | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) $(OBJ_DIR)/App1.o -o $(BIN_DIR)/App1

$(BIN_DIR)/App2 : $(OBJS) $(OBJ_DIR)/App2.o | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) $(OBJ_DIR)/App2.o -o $(BIN_DIR)/App2

$(OBJ_DIR)/App1.o : $(OBJS) $(SRC_DIR)/App1.cpp | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SRC_DIR)/App1.cpp -o $(OBJ_DIR)/App1.o

$(OBJ_DIR)/App2.o : $(SRC_DIR)/App2.cpp | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(SRC_DIR)/App2.cpp -o $(OBJ_DIR)/App2.o

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

-include $(DEPS)
-include $(OBJ_DIR)/App1.d
-include $(OBJ_DIR)/App2.d

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

$(BIN_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)

.PHONY: clean
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).